# Iterating array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to parse it and find if two value exist only once within this array.

Example: "text-success" OR "muted" if EXIST ONCE return the array

if it EXIST twice retrun null

example:

```
Array[6]
0:"text-warning"
1:"text-success"
2:"text-warning"
3:"text-success"
4:"muted"
5:"text-warning"

Array[6]
0:"text-warning"
1:"text-warning"
2:"text-warning"
3:"text-warning"
4:"text-success"
5:"text-warning"

Array[6]
0:"text-warning"
1:"text-warning"
2:"text-warning"
3:"text-success"
4:"muted"
5:"text-warning"

Array[6]
0:"text-warning"
1:"text-warning"
2:"text-warning"
3:"text-warning"
4:"muted"
5:"text-warning"
```

1st one will return FALSE because both exist "text-success"-twice AND "muted"-once

2nd one will return TRUE because it exist ONCE "text-success"

3rd one will return FALSE because both exist "text-success" AND "muted"

4th one will return TRUE because it exist ONCE "muted"

.
.
.
.

and so on

so far this is my Javascript:

```
function singles( array ) {
    for( var index = 0, single = []; index < array.length; index++ ) {
        if( array.indexOf( array[index], array.indexOf( array[index] ) + 1 ) == -1 ) single.push( array[index] );    
    };
    return single;
};
```

it is not working

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple loop with a counter as follows :

```
var count = 0;
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
if(arr[i] == "test-success" || arr[i] == "muted") {
count++;
}
if(count == 1) {
//process array data;
}
```

Comment: the code looks cool, but what if Both "test-success" and "muted" exist then it should not count

Comment: In the 3rd example above muted and success exits once each and the result is false, in this case count will be 2 and thus result false. Only if either muted or success exist once only will it be true. Is this not the case?

Comment: var count = 0;
    for( var index = 0, single = []; index < array.length; index++ ) { 
        if(array[index] == "test-success" || array[index] == "muted") {
            count++;
        }
            if(count == 1) {
                 single.push(array[index]);
            }
    }

    return single;

Comment: the if(count == 1) needs to be outside the for loop.